# How to sort Json value in NSDictionary Objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, json, sorting

I want to sort my nested Json array by location_name, My json is in nsdictionary

Json array is

```
apiResult:{
    Description = "List of Location";
    code = 200;
    locationList =     (
                {
            "location_id" = 481;
            "location_name" = "<null>";
            "pre_fixied" = "$3.00";
            "state_name" = Melbourne;
            status = 0;
            zone = "Zone 2";
            "zone_id" = 30;
        },
                {
            "location_id" = 461;
            "location_name" = "O'Halloran Hill";
            "pre_fixied" = "$5.00";
            "state_name" = Adelaide;
            status = 1;
            zone = "Zone 3";
            "zone_id" = 31;
        },
                {
            "location_id" = 460;
            "location_name" = "Sheidow Park";
            "pre_fixied" = "$5.00";
            "state_name" = Adelaide;
            status = 1;
            zone = "Zone 3";
            "zone_id" = 31;
        },
                {
            "location_id" = 459;
            "location_name" = "Hallett Cove";
            "pre_fixied" = "$5.00";
            "state_name" = Adelaide;
            status = 1;
            zone = "Zone 3";
            "zone_id" = 31;
        },
                {
            "location_id" = 458;
            "location_name" = "Eden Hills";
            "pre_fixied" = "$5.00";
            "state_name" = Adelaide;
            status = 1;
            zone = "Zone 3";
            "zone_id" = 31;
        },
                {
            "location_id" = 457;
            "location_name" = Glengowrie;
            "pre_fixied" = "$5.00";
            "state_name" = Adelaide;
            status = 1;
            zone = "Zone 3";
            "zone_id" = 31;
        }
    );
    message = "List of Location";
    status = Success;
}
```

its appearing by location id descending order i want this json by location name ascending order.
I have sort location list array separately but i want whole json and locationlist by locationname order

Comment: Is there any meaning to sort whole json rather then only locationList ? Because i think you just need to sort locationList list array.

Comment: But i need whole json to pass another page

Comment: Whole json means you need `Description = "List of Location";`
    `code = 200;` `message = "List of Location";`
    `status = Success;`  these all in another page ?

Comment: Yes, in NsMutableDictionary format

Comment: Then create another dictionary, after sorting the location array add `Description`, `code`, `message`, `status` and `sortedArray`  in that dictionary

Comment: But How , i tried but its not give proper format

Comment: how you want and how it is right now?

Comment: i want as it is, like show in my json format above

Comment: How you have added those all in new dictionary can you show?

Comment: [CommonClass hitApi:postParams withUrl:url withResponseCallback:^(NSMutableDictionary*dictResponce){
NSLog(@"dicResponse: %@", dictResponce);
NSArray *extracted = [dictResponce valueForKey:@"locationList"];
NSSortDescriptor *valueDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"location_name" ascending:YES];
NSArray * SoretedArray = [extracted sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[valueDescriptor]];
NSLog(@"Sorted: %@", SoretedArray);
NSMutableDictionary *SortDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[SortDict setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:SoretedArray, nil] forKey:@"locationssList"]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
locationDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"location_id" ascending:YES];
sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject: locationDescriptor];
sortedArray = [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Now change sortedArray into any other format as required.

Comment: But i need whole json (nsmutableDictionary) with sorted location list, i have already sort locationlist separately, but i need whole json in nsmutabledictionary format

Comment: I am just sorted only a part of json.

Answer (score 0):

First short Location Array.

lets say your json result is `NSDictionary *jsonResult;` And filtered array is `NSArray *filteredArray;`

Then

```
    NSMutableDictionary *filteredJson = [NSMutableDictionary new];
    [filteredJson setObject:[jsonResult valueForKey:@"Description"] forKey:@"Description"];
    [filteredJson setObject:[jsonResult valueForKey:@"code"] forKey:@"code"];
    [filteredJson setObject:filteredArray forKey:@"locationList"];
    [filteredJson setObject:[jsonResult valueForKey:@"message"] forKey:@"message"];
    [filteredJson setObject:[jsonResult valueForKey:@"status"] forKey:@"status"];
```